# Swift - number from textfield string checking done in a single line of code

Tags: swift, macos, nsnumberformatter, syntactic-sugar

Hi I've got many fields in an osx app preferences pane that I want to retrieve a string, check if it is a valid number, and if so use it. like this:

```
if let tS = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(sizeTextfield.stringValue) {
    pref.thumbnailSize = Float(tS)
}
```

I'd love to be able to do this in one line like:

```
pref.thumbnailSize = (let tS = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(sizeTextfield.stringValue) != nil) ? Float(tS) : self.pref.thumbnailSize
```

but XCode doesn't like it.

I'm just looking to cut the verbosity down by being able to reuse an intermediary...

I could do:

```
pref.thumbnailSize = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self.thumbnailSizeTextfield.stringValue) != nil ? Float(NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self.thumbnailSizeTextfield.stringValue)) : pref.thumbnailSize
```

but makes the NSNumberFormatter call twice rather than caching the value after the first call...

I feel like there may be some kind of syntactic sugar shortcut (using the ?? operator in conjunction) that can be used here to compress this further, but I can't think of it.  Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, you don't need a number formatter for this application: you can just use `Float(yourString)`

Comment: @AaronBrager good point, however would Float() still return nil if the string doesn't translate or would it return some default value like 0.0?

Comment: It's a "failable initializer" so it'll return `nil` if the string is invalid. You can similarly do `Float(yourString) ?? 0` if you prefer `0` to `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
pref.thumbnailSize = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(sizeTextfield.stringValue)?.floatValue ?? 0
```

Instead of `0` you can provide any default value that you would like to use. If you want `pref.thumbnailSize` to remain unchanged if `numberFromString` returns `nil`, use this:

```
pref.thumbnailSize = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(sizeTextfield.stringValue)?.floatValue ?? pref.thumbnailSize
```

Comment: Oh - I didn't think of that.  So if the numberFromString value is nil, then the .floatValue call won't error out will it?  It will just resolve the whole thing to nil, right?